# Property value after binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox

I have a weird problem and I'm not sure where to look to resolve it.  I have textbox bound to a property that gives all the appearances of being set but is actually not being set.

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtPaintMatchNbr"  Width="100" Text="{Binding paintMatchNbr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Property:

```
    Private _paintMatchNbr As String
Public Property paintMatchNbr As String
    Get
        Return _paintMatchNbr
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _paintMatchNbr = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("paintMatchNbr")
    End Set
End Property
```

If I set breakpoints in the property get/set, I can watch the property being updated.  For example, as "test" is entered into the textbox, a breakpoint at the "_paintMatchNbr = value" statement above shows the property being updated letter-by-letter.

But accessing the property later in the code shows that it's an empty string.

The first thing I looked for is if the property is actually being set to an empty string after "test" entered.  The only place the property is being set to an empty string is in Public Sub New in the class definition. This doesn't occur after "test" entered.

I don't know what else to look for.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that you are dealing with the same instance in both situations?  I don't think that the code provided is enough to help - how is the data context set, how are you accessing the property when it is empty, etc?

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I was creating a new instance of the class and was resetting the property back to an empty string.  I have to admit I don't understand why removing the new instance solved this.  "test" was entered after the new instance was created.  Thanks for your help.